# php exec() never ended

Tags: php, exec

I'm using **php exec()** to run a executable file and it seems never ended.

But running this executable file in shell is ok

Here's the main things the executable file do:

> fork();
>
> child process does some time-wasting things.
>   And I **setrlimit** a CPU time
>
> In parent process: listen signals and kill child process when the used_time calculated exceeds limit

How can I do to make php exec() work?

## Update:

because the code is too long,I just select some of them

### main function

```
child_pid = fork();
if(child_pid == 0)
{
    compile();
    exit(0);
}
else
{


    int res = watch();
    if(res)
        puts("YES");
    else
        puts("NO");
}
```

### child process

```
    LIM.rlim_cur = LIM.rlim_max = COMPILE_TIME;
    setrlimit(RLIMIT_CPU,&LIM);

    alarm(0); 
    alarm(LIM.rlim_cur * 10);
    switch(language)
    {
     //..... here is execl() to call compiler like gcc,g++,javac
    }
```

## parent process

```
   int status = 0;
    int used_time = 0;
    struct timeval case_startv, case_nowv;
    struct timezone case_startz, case_nowz;
    gettimeofday(&case_startv, &case_startz);
    while(1)
    {
        usleep(50000);
        kill(child_pid,SIGKILL);
        gettimeofday(&case_nowv, &case_nowz);
        used_time = case_nowv.tv_sec - case_startv.tv_sec;

        if(waitpid(child_pid,&status,WNOHANG) == 0) //still running
        {
            if(used_time > COMPILE_TIME)
            {
                report_log("Compile time limit exceed");
                kill(child_pid,SIGKILL);
                return 0;

            }
        }
        else
        {
           //handle signals
        }
    }
```

**For test,just the function exec() in php file**

The situation what i said only occurred when :
use php exec() run the executable file to compile user code like:

```
 #include "/dev/random"
    //....
```

Comment: What exactly is the code

Answer (score -1):

Php script on server has limited time to execute. It is generally not a good idea to execute long running scripts this way. It is recommended that they be run as background jobs.

Thi is defined in php.ini which is different for apache and shell

Comment: I meant to write this answer to ask for more clarification as I cannot comment @Wumpus

Answer (score -1):

At last, I find out why this happened..

I just kill childpid but not kill other process cause by childpid

So php exec() will always run